# How to increase number of tested images in MS Azure Custom Vision?

Tags: azure, microsoft-custom-vision, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ai

I've created a project in Azure Custom Vision (Object Detection, General Compact, Tier S0). I uploaded about 70 images, 35 images per tag then started training my model.

Checked tags in the Iterations screen after training (Quick Training) was done. For my surprise, only 7 images were tested per tag.

Tried to run Advanced Training for 1 hour. Nothing has changed. Only 7 images per tag were tested.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a way to use all images for object detection training so it can give me a better accuracy?

Thanks,
+ftex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing in the test interface after the training is only a part of the total images because these metrics are calculated using k-fold cross validation.

You are not doing something wrong. It would not be logic to test all the images because it would mean testing with your training images.

To have a better accuracy, there's no magic: add more images, relevant to your use-case

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/getting-started-build-a-classifier#evaluate-the-classifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/getting-started-build-a-classifier#evaluate-the-classifier?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't hesitate to accept the answer if you find it relevant